# How to Change Color of Button when FireTV remote navigates over it

Tags: java, android-studio, button, background-color, amazon-fire-tv

I am making my first Android App. This is for a firestick.
All done except for the color of the buttons.
The default light gray color is good enough (though I may change this when I find out how to).
When navigating over buttons with the remote control, the color of the button only changes to a slightly darker color. It makes it near impossible to tell which button is being navigated over.
I have gone all through the code and can find nowhere to change this to a darker color.
Changing just the background color stops the color changing at all when it is navigated over.
Where would I change this color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As luck would have it I managed to find the answer just after I posted.
Create xml file in drawable (I used button_events.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@color/primary_dark"/>
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/primary_dark"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/primary" />
</selector>
```

Then I set my buttons background to use this drawable:

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/button_events"/>
```